# Mysql Workbench - Exporting sql script from ER Diagram to database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I created a ER diagram with mysql workbench and I would like to forward engineer it to a specific empty database that is already created.

But the sql script generated with the forward engineer makes it to a database called 'mydb' and I can't import to the database I wish because all the commands at sql script refer to the 'mydb' database.

Also, I didn't find at the Mysql Workbench how to change the database name that will be created by the forward engineer sql script.

How should I proceed to create the database with the sql script and the proper name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the schema name in the schema editor (this is only possible in a model, not when editing live objects in the SQL IDE). Double click on the schema tab:

[image]

This will open the schema editor where you can change the name.